# Random value for BigDecimal

Tags: ruby

I want to generate this value `BigDecimal.new("42.00")`

```
SecureRandom.random_number(100)
```

But how I can generate random amount like this "42.00"?

Comment: Why do you think that `BigDecimal` will give you that format? Because it is recommended for monetary values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[BigDecimal#`new`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.0/libdoc/bigdecimal/rdoc/BigDecimal.html#method-c-new) accepts numeric values as well:

```
a = BigDecimal.new(SecureRandom.random_number(100))
#=> #<BigDecimal:7f88dace71f0,'0.42E2',9(27)>
a.to_f
#=> 42.0
```

Btw, what's the point of double `SecureRandom.random_number`? :)

## edit:

To generate the string of requested format:

```
sprintf( "%0.02f", a)
#=> "42.00"
sprintf( "%0.05f", a)
#=> "42.00000"
```

Comment: I want to generate every time random number. is there any better way?

Comment: @PeterPenzov I showed how to generate random `BigDecimal` instance. No need for double `SecureRandom.random_number`

Comment: Yes, my mistake. But how I can generate number with .00?

Comment: @PeterPenzov `42.0` is equal to `42.00` and equal to `42.0000000000`. If you need a **`String`** instance, than it's another deal.

Comment: Furthermore, `BigDecimal("42.00")` and `BigDecimal(42)` are equal.

Comment: Can you also show me how I can create Sting instance please?

Comment: @PeterPenzov There are many options of formatting the string (which I suck at truly to say). One of them is `sprintf("%d.00", 42)` => `"42.00"`. Google for more

Comment: @PeterPenzov you should rephrase your question accordingly or post a new one.

Comment: @AndreyDeineko should I insert it into BigDecimal? Can you please update your post, please?

Comment: @AndreyDeineko would be great if `sprintf` had a way to specify the precision of ... hey wait ;-)